# Prevent infinite loop on update function that updates itself?

Tags: php, drupal-7, infinite-loop

I'm using Drupal 7 with Commerce, although that doesn't really matter I think.

There's a hook (function) `hook_entity_update()` that is called when an entity (my shopping cart) is updated.

I want to recalculate my shipping in this hook, the issue is that it saves the entity again once the shipping is recalculated and so it calls the hook again, getting me stuck in an infinite loop.

What would be the best way to solve something like this?

I was thinking of using a simple $_SESSION variable, like $_SESSION['updating'] and set it to TRUE at the start of the hook, then set it to FALSE again at the end of the hook and prevent the function from running with a return at the start if the variable is set to true? I'm not sure if this is a good solution?

Using a session variable because it's a form and the function seems to be called multiple times when submitting.
Not sure if a regular variable would work?

One issue I'm already running into is that the variable is somehow not reset at the end of the function and so the function is never called again ...

Comment: Would `hook_entity_presave()` be more appropriate?

Comment: Would cause the same issue I think?

Comment: If you look at the docs (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/7.x) it seems to be for exactly what your asking for.

Comment: Looking at it, but don't see how this would help, could you elaborate? This will just call the update a bit later, but it will still start a new update and still loop in the presave function?

Comment: Just a suggestion - can you try using it.  All your doing is altering the data BEFORE the update, so it shouldn't cause another event to be triggered.  Just in this method calculate your shipping and set the value.

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work - My function calls the Commerce contrib module function commerce_cps_add_order_shipping which calls commerce_order_save, so causes an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the session variable seems to work.
Stupid function is somehow called like 7 times when clicking one button ...

Added this at the start of the function:

```
      // Check if entity is a commerce_order
      if ($type != 'commerce_order') {
        return;
      }

      // Only apply if order is still in cart
      if ($entity->status != 'cart') {
        return;
      }

      if (isset($_SESSION['bab_checkout']['updating']) &&
        $_SESSION['bab_checkout']['updating'] === true) {
        return;
      }
      $_SESSION['bab_checkout']['updating'] = true;
```

And then this at the end of the function:

```
  // We're done updating
  $_SESSION['bab_checkout']['updating'] = false;
```

Still wonder if there is no better solution?